# Play Framework: How to read an entire configuration section consisting of unknown keys

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-config

Here below is how I'd like to configure security profiles for my Play application – each entry in `auth.securityProfiles` consists of an `Operation => Roles` pair:

```
auth {
    securityProfiles {
        myOperation1 = "author, auditor"
        myOperation2 = "admin"
        myOperationN = "auditor, default"
    }
}
```

How do I read all the entries in section `auth.securityProfiles` to produce a `Map` like this?

```
val securityProfiles = Map(
  "myOperation1" -> "author, auditor",
  "myOperation2" -> "admin",
  "myOperationN" -> "auditor, default"
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala?source=cc#L258), and then converting the configuration to map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution... I've just modified the configuration like this...

```
auth {
    securityProfiles = [
        {
            operation = "myOperation1"
            roles = ["author", "auditor"]
        }
        {
            operation = "myOperation2"
            roles = ["admin"]
        }
        {
            operation = "myOperationN"
            roles = ["auditor", "default"]
        }
    ]
}
```

... and then read it with the following code snipper:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

var securityProfiles = Map[String, List[String]]().withDefaultValue(List.empty)
  configuration.getConfigList("auth.securityProfiles").map { _.toList.map { config =>
    config.getString("operation").map { op =>
      securityProfiles += (op -> config.getStringList("roles").map(_.toList).getOrElse(List.empty))
  }
}}
```

I hope that helps.